# Why does a single Flash or video element while loading freeze the entire web page?

Tags: javascript, flash, loading, html

This happens way too often and I finally realized why... you go to a webpage, you're reading or scrolling, then suddenly it freezes and doesn't respond for several seconds... today I (consciously) noticed that it unfroze after a certain box started "playing" (video? interactive content? not sure), so I think it's either Flash or video or something similar in Javascript or something else that's waiting to load and *the entire web page just freezes*...

This is really terrible design/implementation/intention on a web page (though I've seen it in computer operating systems and programs/apps too), and I can't tell if this is intentional or unintentional, but

***is this because of "synchronous" loading, or some quirk with internet technology, or what?***

I can't figure out why these problems still prevent normal usage of our software tools in this day and age.

Subsequently I often leave the page or close the tab or app or whatever, which is completely counter-productive to I'm sure is what the original designer wants.

Comment: Without an example, what do you expect as an answer? Yes, of the billions of websites on the internets there will be poorly written ones that involve video

Comment: Voted to close. This is not an actual **programming** / **technical** Question. Try using Chrome browser with **AdBlock** enabled (download from **extensions** library), also disable some un-needed (by you) extensions & add-ons. Also with it, Flash content shouldn't play unless you click "play" icon... _sometimes_. Not sure what Answer you want really, hence my vote.

Comment: How do I know it's an ad doing it? It could be content intentionally put there by the website owners (such as a news video clip by CNN on cnn.com), so this isn't an ad-specific question. The comments here imply the question was missed, which is more generally: why does an element on the page freeze the whole page (or computer)? It's a programming question because there may be something inherent to web technology allowing this or forcing it, which is why my description box asks: "is this because of "synchronous" loading, or some quirk with internet technology, or what?". Can anyone answer this?